# What is this little strange circle in the middle of the map

Tags: android, android-mapview

I am developing with Google Maps Add-on. I found a little strange circle in the middle of my MapView. **When I scroll the view or tap somewhere else, it's gone.**

I debug the view with Hierarchy View tools, you can see is from inside of MapView, definitely not some misplace view from my code.

[image]

The red marker is from the overlay, just simply pin on the center of this MapView.

Here is the code, pretty standard MapView code:

```
mMapView = new MapView(getActivity(), R.string.key_mapAPIKey);
mMapView.setClickable(false);
mMapView.getController().setZoom(DEFAULT_MAP_ZOOM);
mMapView.getController().animateTo(geoPoint);
mMapView.getOverlays().clear();
mMapView.getOverlays().add(new GoogleMapClassicMarkerOverlay(getResources(), geoPoint));
```

**UPDATE-10/30**

The Overlay is also ordinary, just to show a single marker in the middle, **I remove the overlay but the circle is still there**:

```
public class GoogleMapClassicMarkerOverlay extends ItemizedOverlay<OverlayItem> {

    private GeoPoint mGeoPoint;
    private OverlayItem mItem;

    public GoogleMapClassicMarkerOverlay(Resources res, GeoPoint geoPoint) {
        super(boundCenterBottom(new SafeBitmapDrawable(res, R.drawable.map_marker)));
        mGeoPoint = geoPoint;
        mItem = new OverlayItem(mGeoPoint, "", "");
        populate();
    }

    @Override
    protected OverlayItem createItem(int i) {
        return mItem;
    }

    @Override
        public int size() {
        return 1;
    }
}
```

Anyone has idea how to remove this wired circle?

Comment: Considering that there is no `GoogleMapServiceHelper` nor `GoogleMapClassicMarkerOverlay` in the Maps SDK add-on, this is not "pretty standard MapView code". Your circle is in your overlay, probably from the marker itself.

Comment: Thanks your reply @CommonsWare, I updated the code. I tried remove overlay, but the circle is still there. I keep the Overlay in the code above just to match the screenshot.